# Remove the last character from tag name in tag archive page

Tags: tags

I would remove the last character from tag name in tag archive page, I tried:

```
<?php
echo substr(<?php single_tag_title(); ?>, 0, -1); 
?>
```

but won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here, one is wrong syntax because you're opening and closing PHP tags twice. The second problem is the wrong usage of `single_tag_title()`.

If you want this function to return value instead of outputting it (and you need that because you want to manipulate the string), you need to set the second parameter to false. (see the second example: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_tag_title )

Also it's a good idea to check if you didn't get an empty result.

So your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$tag_title = single_tag_title( '', false );

if ( ! empty( $tag_title ) ) {
    echo substr( $tag_title, 0, -1 );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Levi it works now. How can I obtain same thing in search.php? I tried to substutte single_tag_title with the_search_query, but it won't works.

Comment: Try with `get_search_query()`. It's the same problem - if you use the function, that *displays* the output (with the `echo` or `print`), you won't be able to process is anymore. You need to look for the functions, that *return* the output without displaying it. In WordPress, there is naming convention that helps with that - the functions that start with `the_` (i.e. `the_search_query()` ) display stuff, and the ones starting with `get_` ( `get_search_query()` ) would only return data, so you can process it and display it yourself.

Comment: by the way, please accept my answer if it was helpful :)